# Dynamically adding images to Gallery

Tags: android

The basic user action is dragging/dropping an image from a Gallery to a dropspot. The image that is dropped into the dropspot will populate another Gallery with the same image that was just dropped.

How would I add these "dropped" images into the new Gallery array?

Right now I have standard ImageAdapters linked to each Gallery, with the same array of images in each...would I use an Arrayadapter for the second Gallery instead?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create your own custom ImageAdapter likely by extending BaseAdapter.  The custom adapter would have to allow you to add that image when dropped.

One other item that might help is this link: [Image Adapter adding ImageViews dynamically to GridView without Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814575/image-adapter-adding-imageviews-dynamically-to-gridview-without-cursor).  It's not a complete solution, but it's a start.